# Probability: Why assume an equal relevant magnitude of two mutually exclusive events for P(A|B)?

Tags: probability, statistics

While reading [Grinstead and Snell’s *Introduction to Probability*](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf) p.134, I came across the following:

> "Let Ω = {ω1,ω2,...,ωr} be the original sample space with distribution function m(ωj) assigned. Suppose we learn that the event E has occurred. We want to assign a new distribution function m(ωj|E) to Ω to reflect this fact. Clearly, if a sample point ωj is not in E, we want m(ωj|E) = 0. Moreover, in the absence of information to the contrary, **it is reasonable to assume that the probabilities for ωk in E should have the same relative magnitudes that they had before we learned that E had occurred.**"

I do not study mathematics. I'm reading this on my own so I do not have a professor to ask.

Why must the assumption hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ events, and if you don't know any one of them from any other, and switch two of them around, because of your ignorance, the probabilities remain the same.  Hence the probability of any individual event will be the same as any other.

My guess is that the book is describing Bayesian statistics.  Belief or disbelief in the Bayesian method is like a religion.  So don't expect the arguments to be rigorous.  Note the phrase "it is reasonable to assume" - this phrase is not claiming a ironclad argument.

Comment: Stephen you are correct; This is on Bayesian networks. However, the two events are mutually exclusive (which I should have mentioned), so the occurrence of $$\omega_1$$ in the state space $$\Omega_1$$ _creates_ a state space $$\Omega_2$$, such that $$\{\omega_1\} \cap \Omega_2 = \emptyset$$. I then create a new distribution function for $$\Omega_2$$, which ensures that the relevant magnitude of the probability a specific event (if any), is the same as its occurrence in $$\Omega_1$$. Did I misunderstand your solution, or am I asking the wrong question?

Comment: Yes, in the Bayesian approach, if you know nothing about the relative probabilities between the events in $\Omega_2$, then you would give them all equal probabilities.  So while my solution wasn't complete (because I didn't properly read your question), the solution method still applies.